# "Cannot execute the continuation for Web Service calls" error when using an Asynchronous Callout

Tags: wsdl2apex, asynchronous, continuation

Working through a quick example of using a Continuation to make an async web service callout produced the following error after pressing the apex:commandButton that called the action returning the Continuation.

> Cannot execute the continuation for Web Service calls

[image: Cannot execute the continuation for Web Service calls]

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case it turned out to be the oldest problem in the book with callouts. Hopefully this will save someone a couple of minutes head scratching.

Just as with the synchronous callouts, to make a callout to an asynchronous web service the domain needs to be listed under:

```
Setup > Administration Setup > Security Controls > Remote Site Settings.
```

Comment: Never saw such error message. Good observation.

Comment: Is it acceptable for me to hate myself for ending up here having had this exact problem?!! --- It must be a Friday. Cheers Daniel

Comment: @SimonLawrence - Perfectly acceptable :) In hindsight it seemed obvious, but the error message wasn't very helpful.